# Prevent User from Clicking Button Behind UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a view with several buttons on it. when one of these buttons is clicked, an Image View pops up over all of the other buttons. Even though the image is covering all of the buttons, they are still clickable. Is there a way in XIB to make it so that a user can't click through an Image View? I know I could go in programmatically and disable/enable the buttons one at a time, but I am sure there is a simpler way to do this. Any ideas? Thanks!

One of the recommendations below is that I enable user interaction on the image. However, I am still able to click buttons below the image view. Please see the image as an example.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mark the `UIImageView`'s `userInteractionEnabled` property as YES. This way, it will "steal" the touch events away from the underlying `UIButton`

Comment: hmmm i looked at my XIB and the checkbox called "User Interaction Enabled" is checked, but I am still having trouble. Any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean by "Trouble"? Is the UIButton still accessible? In that case - is the image's alpha 0.0 by any chance? Is it hidden? It must be visible for this effect to work.

Comment: OK got it, there are two checkboxes that say user interaction enabled, one is on the identity inspector, one is on the attributes inspector. I needed to use the one on the attributes inspector. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, failed to mention I wasn't talking about accessibility.